# Is there possible to transfer file from Google Drive to Windows Server IIS?

Tags: windows, iis, server, drive

I generate dailly some files in Google Aps Script like Sheets, Docs, Raports and I want to know how to transfer this file directly to IIS server. Don't expect any ready solution but if you can show me the way how to start or which technology I should use I will be grateful.
I think about Google Script something like fetch API, but doesn't know how "tell the serwer" to collect and save this file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Google Drive API, download the file from Google Drive first, and then transfer it to Windows Server IIS.

More information you can refer to this link: https://developers.google.com/drive.

Comment: Of course I can, but I really like to automation this process, wants to generate file from every hour and transfer for every hour file to windows server. The questions is how to transfer file.

Comment: It’s impossible to transfer directly, you need to download through the app and then transfer.